# Bokeh - Create custom hovertool for a single glyph (overwrite plot hovertool)

Tags: python, hover, bokeh, patch, glyph

I created a map roughly following [the texas.py example](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/texas.html) from Bokeh's documentation. I am trying to add a point on the map that has its own mouseover behavior. The map is created through the following lines:

```
p = figure(
title="Texas Unemployment, 2009", tools=TOOLS,
x_axis_location=None, y_axis_location=None,
tooltips=[
    ("Name", "@name"), ("Unemployment rate)", "@rate%"), ("(Long, Lat)", "($x, $y)")
])
p.grid.grid_line_color = None
p.hover.point_policy = "follow_mouse"

p.patches('x', 'y', source=data,
          fill_color={'field': 'rate', 'transform': color_mapper},
          fill_alpha=0.7, line_color="white", line_width=0.5)
```

I've added the glyph with the following:

```
bc_glyph = Circle(x=barclays_x, y=barclays_y, size=10, line_color="black", fill_color="silver", line_width=1)
p_add = p.add_glyph(bc_glyph)
bc_ht = HoverTool(renderers=[p_add], tooltips='Barclays Stadium')
```

This successfully adds a circle glyph to the plot, but the hovertool follows the behavior of `p.patches`. I would like the circle glyph to display the string 'Barclays Stadium' or have no mouseover behavior. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Adding `p.add_tools(bc_ht)` should probably work, but might give some freak concatenation of the barclays hovertool and the plotwide hovertool.

Comment: That's exactly what happened - the hovertool started behaving very badly (showing more tooltips than could be displayed on-screen). Instead, I rewrote the script to say `p_patches = p.patches('x', 'y', source=data ...etc` and then called `p_hover = HoverTool(renderers=[p_patches])`. That way, the HoverTool only takes effect on the patches glyphs, and leaves the circle glyph alone. Thank you for your advice.